# c++ segmentation fault for dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

I want to add a theater object into a boxoffice object in a C++ code. When I try to add it in main code, first one is added successfully. But a segmentation fault occurs for second and obvioulsy other theater objects. Here is the add function;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BoxOffice.h"

using namespace std;

BoxOffice::BoxOffice()
{
    sizeReserv = 0;
    sizeTheater = 0;
    theaters = new Theater[sizeTheater];
    reserv = new Reservation[sizeReserv];
}

BoxOffice::~BoxOffice(){}

void BoxOffice::addTheater(int theaterId, string movieName, int numRows, int numSeatsPerRow){

    bool theaterExist = false;

    for(int i=0; i<sizeTheater; i++)
    {
        if(theaters[i].id == theaterId)
        {
            theaterExist=true;
        }
    }

    if(theaterExist)
        cout<<"Theater "<<theaterId<<"("<<movieName<<") already exists"<< endl;

    else
    {
        ++sizeTheater;

        Theater *tempTheater = new Theater[sizeTheater];


        if((sizeTheater > 1)){
            tempTheater = theaters;
        }

        tempTheater[sizeTheater-1] = Theater(theaterId,movieName,numRows,numSeatsPerRow);
        delete[] theaters;
        theaters = tempTheater;

        cout<<"Theater "<<theaterId<<"("<<movieName<<") has been added"<< endl;
        cout<<endl;

        delete[] tempTheater;
    }
}
```

And I get segmentation fault on this line;

```
tempTheater[sizeTheater-1] = Theater(theaterId,movieName,numRows,numSeatsPerRow);
```

This is Theater cpp;

```
#include "Theater.h"
using namespace std;

    Theater::Theater(){
        id=0;
        movieName="";
        numRows=0;
        numSeatsPerRow=0;
    }

    Theater::Theater(int TheaterId, string TheaterMovieName, int TheaterNumOfRows, int TheaterNumSeatsPerRow)
    {
        id = TheaterId;
        movieName = TheaterMovieName;
        numRows = TheaterNumOfRows;
        numSeatsPerRow = TheaterNumSeatsPerRow;

        theaterArray = new int*[TheaterNumOfRows];
        for(int i=0;i<TheaterNumOfRows;i++)
            theaterArray[i]= new int[TheaterNumSeatsPerRow];

        for(int i=0; i<TheaterNumOfRows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<TheaterNumSeatsPerRow;j++){
                theaterArray[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
This is header file of Theater;

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Theater{

    public:
        int id;
        string movieName;
        int numRows;
        int numSeatsPerRow;
        int **theaterArray;

        Theater();

        Theater(int TheaterId, string TheaterMovieName, int TheaterNumOfRows, int TheaterNumSeatsPerRow);

};
```

And this is how i call add functions;

```
BoxOffice R;
R.addTheater(10425, "Ted", 4, 3);
R.addTheater(8234, "Cloud Atlas", 8, 3);
R.addTheater(9176, "Hope Springs",6,2);
```

Comment: Use vectors. They are less error prone and good debug compilers offer more checks.

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" when programming in C++, your next thought should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: in fact, as you can see it is a homework and i should find a solution without using vectors :) using vectors is forbidden.

Comment: @black_books - If it is a homework assignment, maybe you should take the time to write your own vector class and use it in your homework.  You learn really nothing substantial juggling new / delete calls in the middle of business logic.

Comment: It's not for me to comment on this but professors who don't teach C++ to the Standard Library aren't doing you any favours.  There are far better languages to teach for that, like Eiffel.

Comment: Even if you fix the issue of overwriting `tempTheater`, and the issue of forgetting to copy the old data to the new memory, you're deleting both `theaters` and `tempTheater`, so when `addTheater` returns, the `theaters` member is an invalid pointer.

Comment: `tempTheater[sizeTheater-1] = Theater(theaterId,movieName,numRows,numSeatsPerRow);`  This is not going to work at all.  Did your teacher mention "the rule of 3" to you?  If not, then you've not been told everything you need to know to get such an assignment to work properly..

Answer (score 2):

The problematic lines are these:

```
    if((sizeTheater > 1)){
        tempTheater = theaters;
    }
```

First you allocate memory and assign it to `tempTheater`, but here you *overwrite* that pointer so it will point to the old memory. It does *not* copy the memory. Since the code is for a homework assignment, I'll leave it up to you how to copy the data, but I do hope you follow [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) for the `Theater` class (as for the `BoxOffice` class) which will make it very simple.

Also, there's no need to allocate a zero-size "array", just make the pointers be `nullptr` (or `0`).

Comment: i try to do it like this (without any if's) but it did not work either. so I try to change it;

for(int i=0; i<sizeTheater; i++)
        {
            tempTheater[i] = theaters[i];
        }

Comment: @black_books The problem with that is that you use the new size when looping. Also please re-read my answer about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).